# Why does this produce the error: "Initializer type is not assignable to variable type Partial<...>"

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-typings

I'm trying to declare TS typings for the popular [retry](https://www.npmjs.com/package/retry) npm package. This package consumes an object for specifying its options, on which all fields are optional. Given that, I thought it was a use case for `Partial<T>` (could be debated of course).

```
export type milliseconds = number;

// Details at: https://www.npmjs.com/package/retry
export declare interface NodeRetryOptions {
    forever: boolean;
    unref: boolean;
    retries: number;
    factor: number;
    minTimeout: milliseconds;
    maxTimeout: milliseconds;
    randomize: number | false;
}

export let MY_EXPONENTIAL_BACKOFF_OPTIONS: Partial<NodeRetryOptions> =
{ forever: true, factor: 2, minTimeout: 7*1000, maxTimeout: 180*1000, randomize: 1.5 };
```

This produces the compile-time error: `Initializer type {forever: boolean, factor: number, minTimeout: number, maxTimeout: number, randomize: number} is not assignable to variable type Partial<NodeRetryOptions>`.

It is solved only by casting the object `as Partial<NodeRetryOptions>`, or by manually changing every field on the interface to be optional. Why does the compiler complain about this?

**Edit:** *using TypeScript 2.4.0.*

Comment: I just pasted your code in the typescript playground and it seems to be working fine. Maybe there's something else causing the problem?

Comment: @toskv Hmm, you're quite right. Maybe it's an IDE-level problem, ie. WebStorm's [TypeScript Language Service](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Language-Service-API) screwing up..? Not my area of expertise.

Comment: I would suggest you just run tsc from the command line in your project and see if that spits out any warnings if it doesn't get a better editor. :)